# error: value split is not a member of (String, Int)

Tags: scala, apache-spark, rdd

I have to use foldByKey on a List to find the max price of each item.
The data, I am using is:

```
val itemPrice= List(("Soap",10),("Toaster",200),("Tshirt",400),("Tshirt",1000),("Suits",8000),("Suits",17000),("Soap",100))
```

When I am trying to split the list into separate small items, it is giving the error:

```
 error: value split is not a member of (String, Int)
```

I want to split the List into inividual small lists and then apply foldbykey on  it like

```
val a = itemPrice.map(st =>st.split(",")).foldByKey(("dummy",0.0))((acc,element)=> if (acc._2>element._2) acc else element)
```

Please help me find the resolution.
Code review and correction will be much helpful.

Comment: Please format your code and provide an expected output. Please refer to [**How to Ask**](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) & [**MCVE**](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: If you want to create a list of lists,  what you want to do is `st.map(List(_))`. You can only use `split` on strings.

Comment: Problem 1: `("Soap",10)` is a tuple, not a string.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you want to make it work by this [example](https://github.com/sanketvega/Spark-1/blob/master/spark-scala/src/main/scala/com/spark/transformations/FoldByKey.scala).

As you can see, you don't need `split`. You have 2 options:

1) Use `fold` -

```
itemPrice.fold(("dummy", 0.0))((acc, element) => {
  (acc,element)=> if (acc._2>element._2) acc else element
})
```

2) Use `foldByKey`, but in that case, you need your to have tuples like:
`List(("a", ("Soap",10)), ("b", ("Toaster", 200))) ..`

and then:

```
`itemPrice.foldByKey(("dummy", 0.0))((acc, element) => {
  (acc,element)=> if (acc._2>element._2) acc else element
})
```

Again, no need to use `split` at all.